# Dataflow pipeline (python) not writing output to GCS

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Beam pipeline in Python 3.8 (using `apache_beam` 2.24.0) running on Dataflow which is not writing the results to GCS.

What I know:

- The Dataflow pipeline runs without issues and if I select the `Write To Gcs` step, it shows me that 10 elements were added and that it ran successfully. However, throughput is 0.
- Running with DirectRunner writes the results to GCS as expected (also the output path is the same so it's not a case of writing to the wrong output path). I'm running on a subnetwork.
- The Service Account I'm using in the DirectRunner is the same as on Dataflow so I don't think it can be a permissions issue on the Service Account
- I'm using `beam.io.WriteToText` to write the results (from googling it seems this should work)

Initially, I thought the subnetwork might be the problem but since the DirectRunner writes the results when I run with the subnetwork flag, I'm not sure that is it.

I'm confused as to how elements would be added in the different transforms throughout the pipeline but throughput is always 0.

I'm running out of ideas as to why this would be happening so would appreciate some pointers!

Comment: So you can write in GCS with DIrectRunner but not with Dataflow? Can you share more information about your pipeline?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I can write to GCS with DirectRunner but not with Dataflow. Happy to, what do you want to know?

Comment: This is surprising. IIRC, gcs is eventually consistent. Did the results never show up? Did the pipeline claim to succeed without any errors?

Comment: @mcansado could be a description of your pipeline showing the operations you used

Comment: The results never show up and the pipeline ran without any errors. The pipeline reads from GCS, does a series of transforms (mostly made of DoFns), a call to an external service and (ideally) writes to GCS. I have also run it without calling the external service (using dummy data instead) and it doesn't write in that case either (but does if I use the DirectRunner).

Comment: Have you tried debugging to understand when your data get lost? Also, do you have some logs or messages that could give us a hint about what is happening?

Comment: I added more details to answer the comments here.

Comment: Are you suing the `DirectRunner` or `DataflowRunner`?